# Get attribute from localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How can I access an object attribute for printing from an object stored in localstorage? For example, if I only want to print the name of the fruit.

```
var fruitBasket = [{"fruit":"Apple","color":"Red","weight":"0.2"},
             {"fruit":"Orange","color":"Orange","weight":"0.3"}];

  var setFruits = localStorage.setItem('fruits', JSON.stringify(fruitBasket));
  var getFruits = localStorage.getItem('fruits');
```

Comment: `var getFruits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fruits'));` - `console.log(getFruits[0].fruit)`

Comment: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem).forEach(function(k) { k && k.fruit && console.log(k.fruit); });`. You should write a wrapper anyway, not even sure if you want print all the fruits or just the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you stringify the JSON, make sure to convert it back to JSON when you want to read it like so `var getFruits = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('fruits') );`

Now you can simply access an object like so: `getFruits[0].fruit;`

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string data into JSON using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var getFruits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fruits'))
```

then iterate over it and access the `fruit` key

```
getFruits.forEach(function(e){console.log(e.fruit)})
```